# How to set to create users permissions in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

i am new to codeigniter. For a project i have three users. SuperAdmin,Admin and users.

There are base controllers :

```
Superadmin_Controller,
Admin_Controller,
User Controller
```

which all `extends to MY_Controller`.

The SuperAdmin will create admin,

We can also set how much users a admin creates. I want that whatever number of user admin asks he can only create that much users.

Till now I have managed to create different credentials for all these users. Now I want to set permission of creating the users to number of users he asked for(no of users fetched from database). So basically what I want to understand is is there any way from which I can restrict the admin to create specific number of user? Please suggest a tutorial.

Comment: set a count(no of user created) in Database and check while creating.

Comment: @PrashantSrivastav Srivasta can you please give me a small example

Comment: Why a vote down? m new to this so couldn't understand this thing

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 fields in database for admin i.e. "users_limit","users_created" where you can store how many no. of users can be created through admin into "users_limit" and increase value of "users_created" value by 1 whenever admin adds the user.

Check the condition whenever admin creates users

```
if ((users_created+1)<users_limit){
    /* allow creating user*/
} else {
    /* Not allowed */
}
```

Comment: Can You please tell me where do i check this logic? the no of users created by the Admin

Comment: You can check it when admin is creating user.

Comment: no i mean where? should this be checked in model or the controller?

Comment: It should be in controller

Comment: Ok lemme give it a try